# Embedding WhatsApp group discussion into website

Tags: embed

WhatsApp groups are popular today. I thought to embed WhatsApp group into a website. Searched on WordPress.org repository but could not find anything. There are many plugins related to WhatsApp chat but none I could locate of WhatsApp group. It would help if someone point to a plugin if already there.

I came across this https://youtu.be/lCmoay0G86M?si=drAOFWvZ-Xt8Ts6F and believe successful implementation could lead me accomplish my goal. As WhatsApp group content are limited to be accessible to its members, I believe the content will not be public. Am I correct or missing something? Also any additional guidance/tips highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd ask the person who wrote the video or the software it's demoing, but it does just shows sending to a group, not reading a group. How would this work? Would users on your website be anonymous members of the group?

Comment: Finding an existing plugin: sorry, I don't know of one, and we don't really do plugin recommendations here. You could start by asking the authors of one of the existing WhatsApp plugins for help extending theirs to groups, if that's actually possible.